# How to remove duplicate options from a dropdown menu in html?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have an html code, where I have a dropdown menu whose values all come from reading a column on a database (in Django). The dropdown menu has several redundancies, I would like to remove those duplicate options.

[Here's the html code part that reads from the database:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBSkg.png)

[And here's the script that should eliminate the duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0qSh.png)

Comment: Don't use images unless it is extremely important. Try providing your code.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on your views.py, can use distinct on filter

```
beacon_id = YUOR_MODEL.objects.filter().distinct(duplicate you want to remove)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get unique values this way

***in views.py***

```
def inputconfiguration(request):
    all_available_states = states_and_districts.objects.all()
    distinct_states = states_and_districts.objects.values("state_name").distinct()
    print(all_available_crops)
    print(distinct_states )
    return render(request, 'your_webpage.html', {"all_available_states": all_available_states, "distinct_states": distinct_states})
```

***Model.py***

```
class states_and_districts(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    district_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```